# Hibernate: How do I get results from a generated many-to-many table?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I've got two tables (Author and Publicaction). These are connected with a many-to-many-table (Writes) which is automatically generated with Hibernate.
Now I want do hava a query like this:

```
SELECT * from Publication p, Writes w 
WHERE w.authorId = ?;
```

the method, that should run this query has the Id from the Author-table as an input.

How can I do this in hql?

Thanks!!

Comment: How are Publication and Writes linked ?

Comment: In HQL, you can access linked Entity tables kindof as if they were related objects (entities) in your program. For retrieving the related publications for an author, you would just write "Select p from Publication p where p.author.id = ?" in HQL, if I remember right.

Comment: @RobertG: that would be right if Publication had a ManyToOne association with AUthor. But it's a ManyToMany, so you need an explicit join, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p from Publication p
inner join p.authors author
where author.id = :authorId
```

Learn about HQL and joins by reading [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

Comment: I had collections of Tenants and Buildings, where each Building contained many tenants nad each of the tenants could live in many buildings. Here is the query I wrote:

`select t from Tenant t inner join t.buildings building where t.username = :tenantUsername and building.id = :buildingId`

I hope this will help someone.